# PowerShell Nesting

Tags: powershell-3.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I am getting the error below while executing the import command and any of the VMware commands are not working inside PowerShell. How do I solve this problem?

```
Import-Module : Cannot load module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere
PowerCLI\Modules\VMware.VimAutomation.Core\VMware.VimAutomation.Core.ps1' because the module nesting limit has been
reached. Modules can only be nested to 10 levels. Please reexamine the order in which you are loading modules so that
they are not as deeply nested then try running your script again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Cis.Core
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Program File...mation.Core.ps1:String) [Import-Module], InvalidOpe
   rationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleTooDeeplyNested,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```